# android:buttonStyle stopped working on material design 1.2.0

Tags: android, material-design

Applying a button style by default on app theme stopped working when material design library was updated to 1.2.1 (possible in 1.2.0 also).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button.GrayGreen</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button.GrayGreen">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Also tried:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button.GrayGreen</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is your "AppTheme.Button.GrayGreen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MaterialButtons use `app:backgroundTint` for background colors and not the `android` attribute. Also, based on documentation which I can see on [material.io](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#theming-buttons) is that when using styling inside `style.xml` or `theme.xml` you need to set the style for every type of MaterialButton component. like this:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button.TextButton</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Button</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>

...
...
```

and so on. Check the link for more, it's all the way down on the page.